# How to understand how fields transform?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, field-theory, inertial-frames, lie-algebra

Let
$$\Phi: M \rightarrow V \otimes \mathfrak{gl}(\mathcal{H})$$
be a quantum field, where $M$ is spacetime and $V$ is a vector. That is, a function of spacetime that outputs a vector with operators over Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ as components. Let $SO^+(1,3)$ be the proper orthochronous homogenous Lorentz group, called the restricted Lorentz group. Suppose $x \in M$ transforms under Lorentz transforms $\Lambda \in SO^+(1,3)$ like
$$x \mapsto \Lambda x.$$

It is said that the field $\Phi$ transforms under $\Lambda \in SO^+(1,3)$ like
$$\Phi(x) \mapsto \pi_V(\Lambda)\Phi(\Lambda^{-1}x) \equiv \Phi'(x)\tag{1}$$
where $\pi_V: SO^+(1,3) \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of the restricted Lorentz group on $V$. Per discussion with ACuriousMind in hbar, (1) comes from the definition of how a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ transforms under a group action $G$ in terms of the action of $G$ on $X$ and $Y$.

However, in Weigand's QFT I & II notes$^{[1]}$ chapter 3, a field is defined as a map
$$\Phi:M \rightarrow V$$
where $V$ is a vector space (whose components are presumably operators in a QFT). We denote the $a^{th}$ component of $\Phi$ by $\Phi^a$. Then, the notes say that the field transforms like
$$\Phi^a(x) \mapsto (\pi_V(\Lambda))^a{}_b\Phi^b(x). \tag{2}$$

The transformation laws (1) and (2) seem to be talking about two distinct "transformations of the field". In particular, (2) does not include an inverse transformation of the coordinates. I would like to know if these transformation laws are indeed talking about distinct definitions of "transformations of the field", or if I am misunderstanding something.

[1] Timo Weigand, *Quantum Field Theory I & II*, https://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf.